# Toggle menu onclick, close by clicking menu link - but only in mobile view

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, toggle

I've made a responsive menu for a one page website that switches to a toggleable menu, when the window width is lower than 768px.
Basically I want the menu to be toggled by a click on the header and closed by another click on a menu link (`li`-element).

My jQuery code so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var e = $("#pull");
    menu = $("#header ul"), $(e).on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(), menu.slideToggle()
    }), $(window).resize(function() {
        menu.is(":hidden") && menu.removeAttr("style")
    })
});
$("#header ul").on("click", "li", function () {
        $("#header ul").hide();
});
```

And a jsfiddle for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/ansoqvms/2/

So opening and closing the menu when clicking on the header works fine. I also got it working that the menu disappears when clicking a menu `li`-element.

**Sadly** the menu not only disappears in mobile view when a menu link is clicked, but also in normal view (> 768px).

I tried working with `if($(window).width() < 768px)`, but it's not that cross browser happy.

I also tried solving the problem with `if($('#pull').is(':visible'))`, since #pull is only visible in mobile view, but it didn't work out as well.

Comment: Why do use `$("#header ul").hide();`? This line hide `ul` when click on one of the `li`.

Comment: Because I want the menu to close when a `li`-element is clicked. Thats what I meant with "menu item". I edited it so it's better to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to recreate your problems with `if($('#pull').is(':visible'))` but for me the following works just fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var e = $("#pull");
    menu = $("#header ul"), $(e).on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(), menu.slideToggle()
    }), $(window).resize(function() {
        menu.is(":hidden") && menu.removeAttr("style")
    })
});
$("#header ul").on("click", "li", function () {
    if($("#pull").is(":visible")) {
        //Use slideToggle() here for a better look and feel of the menu 
        $("#header ul").slideToggle();
    }
});
```

I don't see where your problem might be with this method but this should work just fine

Comment: Thank you! You are absolutely right, it works just wonderful! I have no idead what went wrong in my attempt.

Comment: No problem whatsoever, don't forget the slideToggle() to make it look a bit better, of course, this is your own opinion, but I think practically anyone would prefer the slide over the "poof I'm gone" method @sourg