# Menu navigation error in mobile device

Tags: javascript, css, html, blogger

I had some problems on the blog in mobile display
Can be seen in the picture.

[image: xxxCEKABEL UIxxx]

Problem:

- The navigation menu above, when the click does not appear
- The navigation menu near the search engine, does not appear and can not click

Site : http://cekabel.blogspot.com

Source: http://pastebin.com/AYJjMsL0

Comment: Can you divide your code into 3 different files for HTML, JS & CSS? and maybe load it at https://jsfiddle.net/ so people can have a better look at the working of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this link and re-arrange the header structure.

For more follow this link:

[Toggle menu onclick, close by clicking menu link - but only in mobile view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107017/toggle-menu-onclick-close-by-clicking-menu-link-but-only-in-mobile-view)

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

Add to your code:

```
jQuery('#pull').click(function(){
    jQuery('.top-menunavi > ul').toggleClass('active');
});
```

and to CSS:

```
.active {
    display: block !important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS code before `</head>`

```
<style type="text/css">
    a.menu-slide {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .show {
       display: block !important;
    }
</style>
```

Add this javascript code before `</body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $('#pull').click(function() {
        $('.top-menunavi ul').toggleClass('show');
    });
    $('.menu-slide').click(function() {
        $('.arlina-mainmenu').toggleClass('show');
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

call this function on click event :

```
jQuery('.top-menunavi > ul').toggleClass('active');
```